# validate that user has chosen a jquery collapsible section before form submission

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, validation

I have a Codeigniter form that I want to do some validation for. My issue is that I am making use of a JQuery collapsible list view (not sure of technical name, image below)

[image]

Before the user submits the form I want to ensure that they have selected a 'section header' and secondly that they have provided the required details within that section header.

Can this be done with codeigniter validation class and if not is there a javascript solution for this?

My issue is that no checkbox or value is assigned to a selected header so no info is posted. not sure if there is a jQuery field that is altered on selection?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If there are no form elements to post what do you mean by "provided the required details"?

Comment: This may help http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/LFG8G/1/

Comment: Awesome @sandip, thank you. but if you had three 'section headers' and you only want them to select and populate one. then it must ignore validation for other two 'section headers'. make sense?

Comment: Hi @Rick, the required details will be form elements that I have excluded from the question. so each selection header has its own inputs to complete but the user can only select one selection header. on doing so inputs in the other selection headers are ignored. hope that explains it better.

Comment: Disable the submit button until all the form elements are completed for a section and to cover multiple sections being filled just disable the other headers when the user starts filling one out. You could have a "reset" button to clear the form and let them choose a different one?

Comment: Thanks Rick. Any example of this? appreciate your input and time.